# Error in Wordpress Site, Textbox Abruptly Moves Up

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

My site is www.weardenali.com
I have an error, particularly in the first left image block after the slider, 
with the text "The Perfect Weekender".

When loading the site, the position is at the bottom-left of the screen, as i scroll down, it changes to top-left, which is where it is supposed to be.

I tried checking my CSS if there are any conflicts but I cant seem to find it.

Could anyone assist me with this
Below is the GIF.

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hnw5z.gif)

Thanks!

Comment: Why this question is tagged woocommerce? this is related to Wordpress or Wordpress theming, so please could you remove woocommerce tag. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add this to you css :

```
html.no-js .sf-animation.image-banner-content, .sf-animation.image-banner-content[data-animation="none"] {
 bottom : 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but , This couldn't work, as It moves the entire text of my images up .

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something wrong with an animation somewhere. Is it meant to slide up or something? Try removing the animation from the caption to see if it fixes it. I couldn't replicate in Chrome latest on OSX, but could in FF latest.

Upon inspection, the CSS changes when the caption scrolls into view with some animation classes, which looks like the cause of the issue.

Comment: It's not meant to slide up , hence the issue.. However there's no animation at all .

Comment: @AmritSamtani I know that's why the issue is there, what I mean is that a class is being applied which is being changed by JS when you scroll. Having checked just now in FF again it's no longer doing it, so have you changed something or perhaps it was some cached assets applying the wrong (old) CSS, which was moving it about?